# How can i speed up the insertion of a text file in an SQL database table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bulkinsert

My text file is

```
Town 1, Street Address, Street number 1, Region 1, 125 07
Town 1, Street Address 12, Street number 1, Region 34, 141 07
Town 2, Street Address 345, Street number 1, Region 23, 190 07
Town 2, Street Address 233, Street number 1, Region , 190 11
```

I currently do the following for insertion in an SQL database table.

```
 var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/zipcodes.txt"), Encoding.GetEncoding(1253));
 var Line = fileContents.Split(new string[] {"\n", "\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 var Array = new string[5];
 foreach (string s in Line) 
     {
         Array = s.Split(',');
         storeDB.ZipCodes.Add(new ZipCodes {Town = Array[0], 
                                            StreetAddress = Array[1], 
                                            StreetNumber = Array[2], 
                                            Region = Array[3], 
                                            PostalCode = Array[4].Replace(" ", "")});
     }
     storeDB.SaveChanges();
```

Since the file contains 50000+ records, i would like to insert with another way, faster. Any proposals?

Comment: Import CSV usisng SSMS

Comment: @lad2025 I would like to do it via code

Comment: `BULK
INSERT your_table
FROM '...App_Data/zipcodes.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`BULK INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

```
BULK INSERT db_name.schema.table 
FROM '...path .../zipcodes.txt' 
WITH ( 
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
     );
```

There are many configurations available if needed like `CODEPAGE` or `FIRSTROW` and so on...

Comment: I guess I am doing something terribly wrong.. Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (ZipCodesID).

Comment: @OrElse I don't know your table and full file structure but you can specify `FORMAT FILE` like [here](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/marcoadf/bidn-blog/2479/bulk-insert-format-file-skip-column). The point is the file and table must correspond each other

Answer (score 2):

[SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you looking for (it  is special class to fast load big amount of data into SQL Server):

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
      cn.Open();
      using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))
      {
            copy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
      }
}
```

Just load your CSV to `DataTable` first (it's trivial)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/309564/SQL-Bulk-copy-method-to-insert-large-amount-of-dat